# List hardware devices

Tags: c#, hardware, device-driver

Shortly I will be creating a small application to manage driver installations on our corporate based computers.

The application will run when windows is installed, the application will scan the devices on that computer and read the Hardware Identification information such as vendor, Device Id etc.

it will send the ID's to a database server in turn will reply with some meta data such driver locations etc.

They will then be installed on the system.

My Questions is regarding the lookup of devices, I am looking for the best way to accomplish the collection of the device information, and reading the information surrounding that device such as the Id's etc

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this sample: [Simple Device Manager](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/DevMgr.aspx)

It primarily makes use of the `SetupDi*` functions from the Setup API. You can find a complete reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff549791%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: that is written in C, I was looking for C#, but it's a good start thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) to query devices.

[Querying Computer Hardware with WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394587%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)